# Windows 7 won't update while using FBWF (file based write filter)

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, file-permissions, windows-task-scheduler

Good Morning!  I have a PC running Windows 7 ThinPC.  I found a script on Microsoft's website (located at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff850921.aspx) with instructionson how to set it up.  I try to set it up but nothing ever happens.  Task Manager also says it completed successfully yet the Windows Updates are never applied.  I also checked event viewer and there are no errors listed in regards to this script.

As for my script settings I have it set to run as Administrator and only when it's logged in.  Ideally I would like to have the script run whether or not Administrator is logged in.  Also it's set to run with hightest privileges.  On a bit of a side note I do see on the script's white pages that it's for Windows 7 Embedded.  Now I'm not sure if ThinPC and Embedded are the same thing but since FBWF is built-in to ThinPC I can't imagine that makes much of a difference.

I turned off FBWF and then let the script run at the scheduled time.  However what this does is it will check for updates, write to the log what updates it needs, reboot but then not download and install them.

Does anyone have any familiarity with this and can help me out?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you have to apply both XML Files to the Task Scheduler. The on schedule is used to check for the updates whereas On Startup is used to apply the updates. Hope this helps.